# Dynamic <a> not clickable

Tags: javascript, php

I have done the following code in php so that I can click on the arrow and a form opens below

```
    echo '<div class="editor" id="'.$par_code.'" style=" background-color: #fdfdfd; padding:14px 25px 30px 20px; font-family: Lucida Console, Monaco, monospace; box-shadow: 0 1px 10px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 8px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.03); border-radius: 3px;">'
    .'<img width="50" height="50" style="border-radius:50%" src="images/default.png" alt="Image cannot be displayed"/>'                 
    .'<p class="uname">&nbsp;'.$uname.'</p>&nbsp;'                  
    .'<p class="time">'.$date.'</p>'
    .'<p class="comment-text" style="word-break: break-all;">'.$content.'</p>'
    .'<a class="link-reply al" id="reply" name="'.$par_code.'" style="padding-top: 18px; float: right;"><i class="fa fa-reply fa-lg" title="Reply"></i></a>';
```

My javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a#reply").one("click" , function() {
    var comCode = $(this).attr("name");

    var parent = $(this).parent();
    var str1 = "new-reply";
    var str2 = "tog";
    var res = str1.concat(i);
    var tes = str2.concat(i);


// Create a new editor inside the <div id="editor">, setting its value to html

    parent.append("<br /><center><form action='index.php' method='post' id='"+tes+"'><input class='iptext2' type='text' name='uname2' id='uname2' placeholder='Your Name' required /><div style='padding-bottom:5px'></div><textarea class='ckeditor' name='editor' placeholder='Your Query' id='"+res+"' required></textarea><input type='hidden' name='code' value='"+comCode+"' /><br/><input type='submit' class='form-submit' id='form-reply' name='new_reply' value='Reply' /></form></center>")

    CKEDITOR.replace(res);

    /*
    var x = document.getElementById("tes");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
    */

    i++;

   });
})
```

The following is my css code applied to the anchor tag:

```
.al {
font-size:11.2px;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-decoration: none;
color:#222;
cursor:pointer;
transition:ease 0.3s all;
}
.al:hover {
color:#0072bc;
}
.link-reply {
    color:#767676;
}
```

Here the arrow icon is displayed but is not clickable

Comment: What do you mean by *`"arrow icon is displayed but is not clickable"`* @dark123? Do you mean that the function you pass to `one` isn't executed? Also, where is `i` defined in your code?

Comment: <i> is included in the last line of the php code in between the <a>tag

Comment: I don't mean `<i>`, but `i`; the one you increment at the end of your function.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for dynamic created events on DOM.

```
$(document).on("click","a#reply" , function() { 
   console.log('a#reply => clicked!')
});
```

Or

```
$(body).on("click","a#reply" , function() { 
       console.log('a#reply => clicked!')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code fails, because your `<a>` elements are created dynamically, whereas the event listener is added only to the elements available when the document has loaded.

In order to get your code to work, you need to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/); that is to add the event listener to a common static ancestor, such as the `document` or the `body`, that will in turn delegate it to your target elements.

The methods you can use to achieve this effect in `jQuery` are [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/), with the latter fitting your case better, if you are trying to attach one-time event listeners.

**Code:**

```
$(document).one("click", "a#reply", function() { 
   // ...
});
```